# Running a node.js app with upstart and Procfile

Tags: node.js, upstart, foreman

I have a node.js application.

I have written a Procfile with the following contents.

```
subscription-engine-processor: node index.js
```

Not sure whether i am doing it right, but i tried running it with the ruby gem foreman.

```
$ foreman start
```

nothing happens. The process doesn't run.

Please do comment on whether i am doing it right, if there's any other way of running this is my local. What i ultimately want to do is to export this using upstart when its finally deployed in production.

Comment: There was a bug with dashed-names that was fixed in Foreman 0.63.0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what foreman does, but I can give you the following links so that you can read more in depth tutorials on how to setup Node with Upstart:

http://howtonode.org/deploying-node-upstart-monit 
http://caolanmcmahon.com/posts/deploying_node_js_with_upstart 
http://dailyjs.com/2010/03/15/hosting-nodejs-apps/ 
http://blog.clock.co.uk/2011/04/11/deploying-node-js-apps/

Hope these help.

Comment: I made a change in the the Procfile. Replaced the '-' to '_' in my Procfile and it worked. Now its subscription_engine_processor: node index.js .

Answer (score 1):

You might need this https://github.com/strongloop/node-foreman its a node port of foreman.